# Quickbooks Online API - Set docNumber default auto incrememnt

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm using Keith Palmer's QuickBooks PHP DevKit to create an invoice.  The invoice numbers are being auto generated and auto increment. However, instead of starting from `1000` I was wondering if it would be possible to start from something like `M1000`?

How can this be done?

My HTTP request is:

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <DocNumber>RAPH9750</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2014-12-14</TxnDate>
    <Line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
        <Amount>596.42</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <Description>Cleaning of 2 Rugs.</Description>
        <SalesItemLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
            <ItemRef>21</ItemRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
        <Amount>180</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <Description>Padding</Description>
        <SalesItemLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
            <ItemRef>22</ItemRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <Line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
        <Amount>11.25</Amount>
        <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
        <Description>Padding Tax</Description>
        <SalesItemLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
            <ItemRef>23</ItemRef>
        </SalesItemLineDetail>
    </Line>
    <CustomerRef>62</CustomerRef>
</Invoice>]
```

Comment: Any chance you ever found the answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is getting auto generated based on the company setting of your QBO account. See the below snapshot. It is not possible to control the auto generated docNumber.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  One question remains, however: Where do you define the "custom transaction numbers"?  I was expecting an input field to appear where we can set the prefix or starting custom transaction number.  How can we control the custom generated docNumber?

Comment: As mentioned above, you can't set a desired prefix to this auto generated sequence. If you enable the above setting then in the QBO forms(invoice, bill), you'll see an input field(invoice No/ref no etc depends on the type of entity) to enter free form string as DocNumber.

Comment: I see.  One thing I noticed is that when I enable `custom transaction numbers`, and I enter an invoice manually with an invoice number like `M10006`, the next time I go to create an invoice manually, the invoice field is prepopulated with `M10007`.  I was wondering if I could achieve this same effect when creating invoices via the API, however, it seems like the only way would be to query for the last invoice created, incremement it, and define the invoice number (docNumber) to be equal to that.